# REACTJS.NET SSR - Object doesn't support property or method 'forwardRef'

Tags: reactjs, server-side-rendering, reactjs.net, simplebar

I am trying to render my REACT components via SSR with **REACTJS.NET** in **ASP.NET** project.

In the JS file for SSR, I'm importing **SimpleBar** component from **simplebar-react** package.
This is causing the error ***TypeError: Object doesn't support property or method 'forwardRef'***.

I currently have 2 JS files, one for server and one for client. In the JS for server I am removing the adding of event listeners and similar. However, I can't get away from importing at least the npm package in both JS files.

Any idea on how I can avoid such error?

I am using Webpack + REACTJS.NET version 3.2.0.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after trying a lot of things, this is the best solution I came across.
Before I begin, I am aware that conditional imports is being introduced in ECMA but it isn't working for me, or at least, they way I have the project setup.

Basically, my solution is resolved by mixing **ES6** with **CommonJS** and with help of **Webpack** and **babel**.

In Webpack I am creating a plugin:

[image]

And in code, when I want to import the Simplebar react component, I do the following in the constructor:
[image]

And then, whenever I want to use my imported component, I do the following:
[image]

This was the best way I found in order to render with SSR. I think it's okay since the content between **server** and **client** side are the same.

Does anyone know a better solution? Or do you have concerns?

Comment: It's really preferable for you to include code as formatted text rather than pictures of it